# Not able to connect to mysql server from PyQt5

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt

I am trying to connect to MySQL data base through `QtSql.QSqlDatabase` class in PyQt5.
Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtSql
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase()
db.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("*****") #correct password here
db.setDatabaseName("root")
print(db.open())
print(db.lastError().text())
print(db.drivers())
```

I always get error as `Driver not loaded`. Here is the o/p from my code:

```
False
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
```

PyQt5 is 64bit version built with python3.
Mysql server is running.
There contents of C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\sqldrivers is:

[image: list of sql drivers]

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was here

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase()
db.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
```

as `addDatabase` is a static function.
Correct code is this

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
```